# Storing complex objects in memory in a web application?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, redis

For each user in my nodejs application, I need to store objects that look something like this (I'm using JSON merely to represent the data):

```
{
    id: 12345,
    name: "John Smith",
    count: 5,
    status: 0,
    msgs: ["message1", "message2", "message3"],
        title: "this is a title"
}
```

My options so far -

- Put them in mongoDB. This doesn't seem like a good idea since I'll be reading and writing to them very often (every few minutes).
- Put them in a Redis store. This seems OK, but I cannot create complex objects directly. Serializing/Deserializing each object seems painful.

What's the best way to store them? What are my other options?

Comment: This question is too broad right now for an effective answer (as nearly any data storage structure would fit your requirements). What types of queries do you need to do, how many users, why is writing to disk every few minutes a problem, what type of high availability do you need, do you have existing skills in a platform that could be leveraged, is price a concern, who will be managing the servers, etc.?

Answer (score -1):

Have you also checked CouchDB? http://couchdb.apache.org/